# Ubuntu 22.04 server installer does not create btrfs subvolumes?

Tags: server, 22.04, btrfs

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS server today and selected BTRFS as for the `/` partition. Here is the scheme I selected in the custom installation:

```
/boot     2G ext4
/boot/efi 1G fat32
SWAP      4G
/         469.9G btrfs
```

From searching around, I saw that ubuntu used to create two separate subvolumes under `@` and `@home`, but I don't see them when I check:

```
# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0    62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1587
loop1         7:1    0  79.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22923
loop2         7:2    0    47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16292
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 469.9G  0 part /
```

```
# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/disk/by-uuid/8b2ff495-b8b2-4959-a5a4-1f4aa7e85ffe none swap sw 0 0
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4466d07c-a9a8-452b-a970-667f55eff17a / btrfs defaults 0 1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/d15e9776-60c0-4e5f-b782-087126cfde2f /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/E1C9-D08B /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

```
# mount | grep nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p4 on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,ssd,space_cache=v2,subvolid=5,subvol=/)
```

Did I miss something during installation?

I don't think this is a duplicate considering Ubuntu switched to the subquity installer recently, and the installation flow seemed to have changed from when the previous questions on this topic were answered.

Answer (score 2):

It is a standard setup for a `btrfs` file system with `@` and `@home` subvolumes.

`@` is mounted to `/` and `@home` is mounted to `/home`.

It looks like `subuiquity` doesn't do it. You can fix it.
Boot from a LiveUSB and run from there:

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p4 /mnt
```

Run `sudo nano /mnt/etc/fstab`, remove this line

```
 /dev/disk/by-uuid/4466d07c-a9a8-452b-a970-667f55eff17a / btrfs defaults 0 1
```

and add these lines:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4466d07c-a9a8-452b-a970-667f55eff17a / btrfs subvol=@ 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4466d07c-a9a8-452b-a970-667f55eff17a /home btrfs subvol=@home 0 0
```

Then run:

```
sudo btrfs sub create /mnt/@
sudo btrfs sub create /mnt/@home
sudo mv /mnt/home/* /mnt/@home
cd /mnt
sudo mv !(@|swapfile) /mnt/@
sync
sudo umount /mnt
sudo mount -o subvol=@ /dev/nvme0n1p4 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/boot
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo update-grub
exit
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt/boot
sudo umount /mnt
```

Reboot, and if I didn't make a mistake, all should work.

Comment: Hi, I don't have either the @ or @home subvolumes. Please see the update for the contents of `/etc/fstab` and `mount | grep nvme0n1p4`.

Comment: You can leave it as is, or create the subvolumes and fix `/etc/fstab` if you like. I can give directions.

Comment: Yes, could you give instructions on how to do that?

Comment: Hold on, I will update the answer. If you have important data, do a backup.

Comment: I got "cannot move /mnt/@ to a subdirectory of itself  /mnt/@/@" for the second mv command

Comment: Oops. I will fix it.

Comment: Check if `update-grub` doesn't  give errors. You can continue from the place you stopped.

Comment: The mount command returns: "mount: /media: can't find in /etc/fstab"

Comment: A typo, no device. Sry.

Comment: Looks like about half the installation folders are in /mnt and half under /mnt/@, should I just complete the mv manually?

Comment: What do you mean by "installation folders"? If it is under `/home`, they will be moved. Some won't disappear from `/mnt` like `/sys`. Now it looks OK. If you continue, all should work well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139766/discussion-between-tcapwasraw-and-pilot6).